# Serialize objects with Gson into arbitrary JSON arrays without getting warnings

Tags: java, gson

I need to serialize an object like this:

```
class A {
    int a = 1;
    String b = "hello";
    boolean isDog = false;
}
```

into JSON array like this:

```
[1,"hello",false]
```

I know one (wrong) way to do this: create an untyped Collection out of object's fields and then Gson it:

```
class A {
    // ...
    Collection forGson() {
        ArrayList col = new ArrayList();
        col.add(a);
        col.add(b);
        col.add(c);
        return col;
    } 
}
new Gson().toJson(new A().forGson());
```

But it produces a lot of warnings because of untyped collections usage. So is there any way to serialize objects into an array of arbitrary types without getting any warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is literally "You're doing it wrong". You don't have an array of random things, you have an (`A`) object. It has *nothing* in common with the JSON you want to produce.

That being said, if you really wanted to do this, you supply your own Serializer / Deserializer to `Gson`:

```
class ASerializer implements JsonSerializer<A>
{

    public JsonElement serialize(A t, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsc)
    {
        JsonArray ja = new JsonArray();
        ja.add(new JsonPrimitive(t.a));
        ja.add(new JsonPrimitive(t.b));
        ja.add(new JsonPrimitive(t.isDog));
        return ja;
    }

}
```

You'd create a `JsonDeserializer` that did the reverse, creating a `A` object from the supplied JSON array.

See: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization for more info.

Then using `GsonBuilder` you'd tell `Gson` to use them:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 
builder.registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new ASerializer());
builder.registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new ADeserializer());
Gson gson = builder.create(); 
...
```